# Destroying tkinter Labels

Tags: python, tkinter, label

I'm Really Stuck In A Problem Here.
This Is My Code,I Was Trying To Make A Word Guess Game:

```
from random_words import RandomWords
t = Tk()
rw = RandomWords()
word = rw.random_word()
tt = "*" * len(word)
attempts = len(word) - len(word) // 3
l1 = Label(t,text="This Is Word Guessing Game.\nThere Will Be A Secret Word And You Will Try Every Time To Guess A Letter In It Till The Word Is Completely Guessed.\nGood Luck!")
l2 = Label(t,text=f"\nYou Should Enter One Letter In The Lower Case.\nAnyways,Only The First Letter Of Your Input Will Be Taken In The Lower Case.\nThe Word Consists Of {len(word)} Characters")
l1.grid(row=0, column=0)
l2.grid(row=1, column=0)
def onclick(event):
    if guessi.get() == "Enter Your Guess: ":
        guessi.delete(0, END)
def end():
    b2.destroy()
    guessi.destroy()
    Label(t, text=f"\nGame Over\n{wol}").grid(row=5, column=0)
    Label(t, text=f"\nThe Correct Word Is: {word}").grid(row=6, column=0)
def Try():
    global guess, attempts, tt
    statement = StringVar()
    hh = guessi.get()
    guess = str(hh)
    if guess != "" and guess != "Enter Your Guess: ":
        guess = guess[0].lower()
        if guess in word:
            r = "Correct Guess!"
            pos = word.index(guess)
            if guess in tt:
                if word.count(guess) < (tt + guess).count(guess):
                    r = "Wrong guess"
                    attempts -= 1
                else:
                    pos = word.index(guess, pos + 1)
            tt = tt[:pos] + guess + tt[pos + 1:]
            statement.set(f"\n{r}\nThe Current Word Is: {tt}")
        else:
            r = "Wrong Guess"
            statement.set(f"\n{r}\nThe Current Word Is: {tt}")
            attempts -= 1
        global ll1, l3
        ll1 = Label(t, textvariable=statement)
        ll1.grid(row=4, column=0)
        ar = StringVar()
        ar.set(f"Attempts Remaining: {attempts}")
        l3 = Label(t, textvariable=ar)
        l3.grid(row=0, column=0)
        global wol
        if attempts == 0:
            wol = "You Lost"
            end()
        if tt == word:
            wol = "You Won"
            end()
def start():
    l1.destroy()
    l2.destroy()
    b1.destroy()
    global guessi, b2
    Label(t, text=f"Attempts Remaining: {attempts}").grid(row=0, column=0)
    guessi = Entry(t, width=20, borderwidth=20)
    guessi.insert(0, "Enter Your Guess: ")
    guessi.bind("<FocusIn>", onclick)
    guessi.grid(row=1, column=0)
    b2 = Button(t, text="Try", command=Try)
    b2.grid(row=2, column=0)
b1 = Button(t, text="Start", command=start)
b1.grid(row=2, column=0)
t.mainloop()
```

In Line 50:
My Problem Is That When The Players Attempts Turn To Zero,Some Labels Which Should Be Destroyed As I Put This In An If statement,But..They Are Not Destroyed.
My Mind Is Blowing And I Don't Know Why This Happens,Please Help!

Comment: The problem might be that you can't access `l1`, `l2` and `l3` from outside of the function you've created them in. Use `global` keywoard for that, but be careful and don't overuse it! Use OOP to your advantage!

Comment: I Tried To Make It Inside The Function And It Didn't Work

Comment: Use global variables.

Comment: I Have Already Uesd Them.

Comment: Like @БогданОпир said, use OOP to your advantage! Look [here](https://pythonprogramming.net/object-oriented-programming-crash-course-tkinter/) to get started.